# Windows Uninstall using REG Query to log

Tags: batch-file, registry, wmic

First of all, a tip of the hat to Rob van der Woude for his fantastic script.
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/getuninstall_w7.txt
His script is Windows 7 specific and is not focused on the enterprise.  His script does however, provide some very valuable insights for us to leverage.

Other resources utilized:

- http://geekuninstaller.com
- http://ss64.com/nt/installed.txt

Have also seen a number of scripts related to this that are based on VBS and PowerShell.  While these are fine, we have some issues with those file formats as discussed below.

**CURRENT ISSUE:** We are seeing is that detection between 32-bit and 64-bit uninstall registry key does not appear to be working properly.  We are using FINDSTR with RegExP as Rob's website points out above.  Did try to remove the /R and /C: but could get significant headway on this.

We are filtering WinZip - even if installed on a 64-bit server, appears to be installed at the 32-bit uninstall location.  This may not be a very good example for this exercise.

Resulting log shows correctly for 32-bit:

```
SOMESERVER
SOMESERVER,"32bit",WinZip Command Line Support Add-On 3.2 
SOMESERVER,"32bit",WinZip 16.5 
SOMESERVER,"32bit",16.5.10095
```

Resulting log shows incorrectly for 64-bit (I suspect we need to clear a variable or two):

```
ANOTHERSERVER
ANOTHERSERVER,"32bit",WinZip Command Line Support Add-On 3.2 
ANOTHERSERVER,"64bit",WinZip Command Line Support Add-On 3.2
```

We would expect the log for 64-bit:

```
ANOTHERSERVER
ANOTHERSERVER,"32bit",WinZip Command Line Support Add-On 3.2 
ANOTHERSERVER,"64bit",WinZip 16.5 
ANOTHERSERVER,"64bit",16.5.10095
```

Again, as discussed above, WinZip maybe a bad example for this. :)

Current script code is:

```
REM TITLE: Installed Software
REM AUTHOR: Kent Dyer (WITH PIECES PULLED FROM VARIOUS RESOURCES - REFERENCED BELOW)
REM DATE: 2014-02-27
REM VERSION: 1.0 (Initial release)
REM
REM TO DO: This script is to read a text file and does not query AD
REM 
REM Have read the warnings against the use of Win32_Product and in fact does not exist
REM on newer systems.  It just simply errors with the use of WMIC (VBS: http://ss64.com/nt/installed.txt)
REM ISSUE #1: Because of security issues in our enterprise data center, we cannot use VBS without code signing
REM ISSUE #2: PowerShell is certainly an option, but like the batch file as below
REM ISSUE #3: have seen on a certain number of systems where the 32 and 64 bit remote registry key detection
REM The FINDSTR is using with RegExp..
REM is not working properly in some example
REM Geek Uninstaller (http://geekuninstaller.com) shows WinZip-64 (VERSION 16.5.10095) being referenced
REM in the registry at the 32-bit location:
REM HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240D3}
REM
REM ISSUE STATEMENT AND DISCUSSION
REM Have seen a number of scripts out on various sites using VBS and PowerShell
REM However, they do not address if there is no "DisplayName" like the one below
REM and consequently have a number of errors when run
REM Gained some very valuable insight at: Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages
REM URL: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/getuninstall_w7.txt
REM However the page is specific to windows 7 only
REM We have a number of Windows 2003/2008 servers and have a mix of 32 and 64-bit installations
REM WinZip in the example shown does have both 32-bit and 64-bit installations to illustrate
REM the use of this script

REM DEFINE A LIST OF COMPUTERS
SET COMPLIST=installed_computers.txt

REM CREATE A LOG
SET LOGDATA=results.txt

REM SOFTWARE TO SEARCH FOR.  HAVE ONLY USED PARTIAL STRINGS.
REM HAVE NOT USED FULL STRINGS LIKE WinZip 16.5
SET SRCH=WinZip

REM WE NEED TO DELETE THE EXISTING LOG IF IT EXISTS
IF EXIST %LOGDATA% DEL %LOGDATA%

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET Count32bit=0
SET Count64bit=0
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN (%COMPLIST%) DO (
  SET CNAME=%%A
  ECHO !CNAME! >> %LOGDATA%
REM SECTION TO LIST 32-BIT SOFTWARE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('REG Query \\!CNAME!\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\') DO (
REM USE THIS NEXT LINE TO LIST ALL 32-BIT SOFTWARE
REM USE THIS FOR EVERYTHING... REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName /E | FINDSTR /R /I /C:" DisplayName .* .*%~1" >NUL 2>&1
REM USE THIS NEXT LINE TO LIST SPECIFIC 32-bit SOFTWARE
REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName /E | FINDSTR  /R /I /C:" DisplayName .* .*%SRCH%*" >NUL 2>&1
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
              SET /A Count32bit += 1
              FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /v DisplayName') DO ECHO !CNAME!,"32bit",%%C >> %LOGDATA%
              FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /v DisplayVersion') DO ECHO !CNAME!,"32bit",%%C >> %LOGDATA%
              )
)
REM
REM SECTION TO LIST 64-BIT SOFTWARE
REM SEEM TO HAVE A BIT OF AN ISSUE WITH
REM WinZip command-line add-on
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('REG Query \\!CNAME!\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\') DO (
REM USE THIS NEXT LINE TO LIST ALL 64-BIT SOFTWARE
REM USE THIS FOR EVERYTHING... REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName /E | FINDSTR /R /I /C:" DisplayName .* .*%~1" >NUL 2>&1
REM USE THIS NEXT LINE TO LIST SPECIFC 64-bit SOFTWARE
REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName /E | FINDSTR /R /I /C:" DisplayName .* .*%SRCH%*" >NUL 2>&1
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
              SET /A Count64bit += 1
              FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /v DisplayName') DO ECHO !CNAME!,"64bit",%%C >> %LOGDATA%
              FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /v DisplayVersion') DO ECHO !CNAME!,"64bit",%%C >> %LOGDATA%
              )
)

)
    ECHO. >> %LOGDATA%
    ECHO     !Count64bit! 64-bit programs and !Count32bit! 32-bit programs found >> %LOGDATA%
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the code so that it is now working.

Have also seen a number of scripts related to this that are based on VBS and PowerShell.  While these are fine, we have some issues with those file formats as discussed below.

Resulting log shows correctly for 32-bit:

```
SOMESERVER,32BIT,"WinZip Command Line Support Add-On 3.2","", 
SOMESERVER,32BIT,"WinZip 16.5","16.5.10095",2012-07-24
```

Resulting log shows correctly for 64-bit:

```
ANOTHERSERVER,32BIT,"WinZip 16.5","16.5.10095",2012-11-13 
ANOTHERSERVER,64BIT,"WinZip Command Line Support Add-On 3.2","",
```

Current script code is:

```
REM TITLE: Installed Software
REM AUTHOR: Kent Dyer (WITH PIECES PULLED FROM VARIOUS RESOURCES - REFERENCED BELOW)
REM DATE: 2014-02-27
REM VERSION: 1.0 (Initial release)
REM
REM TO DO: This script is to read a text file and does not query AD
REM 
REM Have read the warnings against the use of Win32_Product and in fact does not exist
REM on newer systems.  It just simply errors with the use of WMIC (VBS: http://ss64.com/nt/installed.txt)
REM ISSUE #1: Because security issues in our enterprise data center, we cannot use VBS without code signing
REM ISSUE #2: PowerShell is certainly an option, but like the batch file as below
REM ISSUE #3: have seen on a certain number of systems where the 32 and 64 bit remote registry key detection
REM Yout must run this script on a 64-bit machine.  While you can run it on the 32-bit environment, in
REM to see the 64-bit environent, you have to execute this scrip this week.
REM Geek Uninstaller (http://geekuninstaller.com) shows WinZip-64 (VERSION 16.5.10095) being referenced
REM in the registry at the 32-bit location:
REM HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240D3}
REM
REM ISSUE STATEMENT AND DISCUSSION
REM Have seen a number of scripts out on various sites using VBS and PowerShell
REM However, they do not address if there is no "DisplayName" like the one below
REM and consequently have a number of errors when run
REM Gained some very valuable insight at: Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages
REM URL: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/getuninstall_w7.txt
REM However the page is specific to windows 7 only
REM We have a number of Windows 2003/2008 servers and have a mix of 32 and 64-bit installations
REM WinZip in the example shown does have both 32-bit and 64-bit installations to illustrate
REM the use of this script

REM DEFINE A LIST OF COMPUTERS
SET COMPLIST=installed_computers.txt

REM CREATE A LOG
SET LOGDATA=results.txt

REM SOFTWARE TO SEARCH FOR.  HAVE ONLY USED PARTIAL STRINGS.
REM HAVE NOT USED FULL STRINGS LIKE WinZip 16.5
SET SRCH=WinZip

REM WE NEED TO DELETE THE EXISTING LOG IF IT EXISTS
IF EXIST %LOGDATA% DEL %LOGDATA%

ECHO DisplayName,DisplayVersion,InstallDate >> %LOGDATA%

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN (%COMPLIST%) DO (
 SET CNAME=%%A
  rem SET CNAME=LTCRSADEVAP06
  REM ECHO !CNAME! >> %LOGDATA%
REM SECTION TO LIST 32-BIT SOFTWARE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('REG Query \\!CNAME!\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /F "%~1" /D /S 2^>NUL ^| FINDSTR /R /B /C:"HKEY_"') DO (
        REM USE THIS NEXT LINE TO LIST SPECIFC 32-BIT SOFTWARE
        REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName /E | FINDSTR /R /I /C:" DisplayName .* .*!SRCH!" >NUL 2>&1
        REM USE THIS NEXT LINE TO LIST ALL 32-BIT SOFTWARE
    REM REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName /V /E | FINDSTR /R /I /C:" DisplayName .* .*%~1" >NUL 2>&1
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        SET /A Count += 1
        FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName    /V /E 2^>NUL ^| FIND /I " DisplayName "')     DO (
         SET DisplayName=%%C
         )
        FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayVersion /V /E 2^>NUL ^| FIND /I " DisplayVersion "')  DO (
         SET DisplayVersion=%%C
         )
        FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F InstallDate    /V /E 2^>NUL ^| FIND /I " InstallDate "')     DO (
            SET InstallDate=%%C
            SET InstallDate=!InstallDate:~0,4!-!InstallDate:~4,2!-!InstallDate:~6!
        )
        ECHO.
        ECHO !CNAME!,32BIT,"!DisplayName!","!DisplayVersion!",!InstallDate! >> %LOGDATA%
        SET DisplayName=
        SET DisplayVersion=
        SET InstallDate=
    )
)

REM IF YOU DO NOT RUN THIS ON A 64-BIT SYSTEM, IT WILL NEVER DETECT 64-BIT SOFTWARE!!
WMIC.EXE Path Win32_Processor Get DataWidth 2>NUL | FIND "64" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO.
    ECHO %Count% programs found
) ELSE (
    SET Count32bit=0
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('REG Query \\!CNAME!\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /F "%~1" /D /S 2^>NUL ^| FINDSTR /R /B /C:"HKEY_"') DO (
                REM USE THIS NEXT LINE TO LIST SPECIFC 64-bit SOFTWARE
                REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName /E | FINDSTR /R /I /C:" DisplayName .* .*!SRCH!" >NUL 2>&1
                REM USE THIS NEXT LINE TO LIST ALL 64-BIT SOFTWARE
        REM REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName /V /E | FINDSTR /R /I /C:" DisplayName .* .*%~1" >NUL 2>&1
        IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
            SET /A Count32bit += 1
            FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayName    /V /E 2^>NUL ^| FIND /I " DisplayName "')     DO (
             SET DisplayName=%%C
             )
            FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F DisplayVersion /V /E 2^>NUL ^| FIND /I " DisplayVersion "')  DO (
             SET DisplayVersion=%%C
             )
            FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "\\!CNAME!\%%~A" /F InstallDate    /V /E 2^>NUL ^| FIND /I " InstallDate "')     DO (
                SET InstallDate=%%C
                SET InstallDate=!InstallDate:~0,4!-!InstallDate:~4,2!-!InstallDate:~6!
            )
            ECHO.
            ECHO !CNAME!,64BIT,"!DisplayName!","!DisplayVersion!",!InstallDate! >> %LOGDATA%
            SET DisplayName=
            SET DisplayVersion=
            SET InstallDate=
        )
    )
)
)
    ECHO. >> %LOGDATA%
    ECHO     %Count% 64-bit programs and !Count32bit! 32-bit programs found >> %LOGDATA%
PAUSE
```